# Cannot write the output to a text file in cpp program

Tags: c++, file-handling

I have this input file "https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard/do/A-large-practice.in?cmd=GetInputFile&problem=374101&input_id=1&filename=A-large-practice.in&redownload_last=1&agent=website&csrfmiddlewaretoken=OWMxNTVmMTUyODBiYjhhN2Q2OTM3ZGJiMTNhNDkwMDF8fDEzNzIxNzI1NTE3ODAzMjA%3D" 
I tried to read this file :-using freopen("filename.txt",r,stdin); and then I wanted  the output written to be written to another text file which I can upload in this codejam practice question for the judge.

```
#include<iostream>
   #include<cstdio>
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
     int t,k=0,a[2000];
     freopen("ab.txt","r",stdin);

     scanf("%d",&t);

     while(t--)
     {
         freopen("cb.txt","w",stdout);

         int c;

         scanf("%d",&c);
         int n;
         scanf("%d",&n);
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         scanf("%d",&a[i]);

         printf("Case #%d: ",++k);
         for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
         {for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
          if((a[i]+a[j])==c)
           {printf("%d %d\n",i+1,j+1);
             i=n;}
           }

     }
     return 0;
    }
```

This is my code.
Now the problem is the output file cb.txt contains only the last line of the input. I want the the whole of the output to be written to cb.txt,so what should I do.

Comment: Yes, one plus sign can make all the difference.

Comment: You mean w+ ,sorry I am new to file handling

Comment: It's probably much easier on you to use C++ I/O instead of C. It's type safe and easy to read, plus you get file streams that close themselves when they're done.

Comment: after converting to C++I/O, I get the same error

Comment: Did you pass `std::ios::app`?

Comment: I got my mistake , I was putting freopen("cb.txt","w",stdout); inside the loop so the output was getting overwritten each time,now I put this line outside the loop and it works

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the console input (`scanf`) confused with the file input (`fscanf`).

The C-style functions for file I/O have an *f* prefix.
See:  `fprintf, fscanf, fgets, and fputs`.

Answer (score 0):

I got my mistake , I was putting freopen("cb.txt","w",stdout); inside the loop so the output was getting overwritten each time,now I put this line outside the loop and it works